# 'Abort CronJob' botton is not visible in HMC?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I created a **cronjob** in hybris 6.1. In *HMC* '**Start CronJob now**' button is there to start cron job but '**Abort CronJob**' button is not showing.What to do ????

Comment: No..Please read the question.

Comment: Today I extracted a new suite and created a cronjob. But in in HMC abort button is not showing, It is not there. I closed everything and tried to start from the scratch but it's still not working.

Comment: HMC has been deprecated from hybris..just check in backoffice

Comment: I added HMC extension in localextension.xml .

Comment: Check this it may help : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/create-abortable-job-sap-hybris/

Answer (score 1):

All jobs are not abortable. To be abortable a job must implement the `isAbortable` method and return `true`.

Example :

```
@Override
public boolean isAbortable()
{
  return true;
}
```

See [Writing an Abortable Job](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8be670d686691014bdbfac79c33da20e.html).